# Why is there a guard band in ADSL

Tags: digital-logic, communication, modulation

I recently learned about ADSL and its modulation method DMT.

I know the frequency spectrum is split up into a number of orthoganally spaced bins:
Voice(PSTN) - Guard Band - Upstream - Downstream

Seeing as these bins are orthoganally spaced to prevent inter-bin interference, what is the use of the guard band between the PSTN frequencies and the upstream frequencies? The same goes for the small guard bin between the upstream and downstream.

I am by no means an expert in this area, so my apologies if I made a fundamental mistake at understanding this method.

Thank you in advance

Comment: For engineering purposes.

Comment: I don't know, but this is my surmise: The guard band isn't required within the transmitter's block, nor the receiver's block, but is between the blocks to separate the blocks out - makes splitting the blocks easier with filters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The guard bands are required because filters aren't perfect.

A filter that can pass 8,000 Hz but block 8,001 Hz must have a group delay of at least 1s. Building a circuit that a signal takes 1s to pass through requires an awful lot of material and space, so we have to make do with a flatter slope, e.g. passing 8 kHz but blocking 10 kHz, so any DSL traffic can only use frequencies that are adequately blocked in the filter for the analog line.

The same thing is between up- and downstream. The receiver uses a filter to block out the signal from the transmitter, allowing a higher gain on the receive amplifier.

Comment: Think of it like the central reservation on a motorway / freeway. You don't have anything between the lanes on each side of the road, but you do need to separate the two directions from each other to stop the cars colliding.